# Custom Py Module: Intra Module Importing

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, circular-reference

I am creating a custom Python module that I wanted to work similarly to something like numpy where most of the functionality can be accessed by calling np.function() or what have you. However, in creating my submodules and __init__.py file, I *think* that I've run into a circular import reference. Here's what I'm trying to do and the error I'm seeing, any tips to help me get this working the way I envisioned are greatly appreciated:

Let's call the module "foobar" and say I have a folder named "foobar" on the path and in this folder are three py files: "__init__.py", "foo.py", and "bar.py".

An example of submodule 1, "foo.py":

```
import bar
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def runfunc(self):
        bar.func()
```

An example of submodule 2, "bar.py":

```
import foo
def func():
    f=foo.F()
```

An example of __init__.py:

```
import numpy
from foo import *
from bar import *

__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']
```

So what I perceive to be my issue is that when foo is imported, it imports bar, which imports foo, which creates a loop (in my mind). I am also confused as to the use of __init__.py if, when it is called and imports other modules they cannot see each other when executing (i.e. I need to import bar into foo even though __init__.py did this).

When I run something from a script trying to import the entire module, I get the error in bar.py "ImportError: cannot import name foo". I am actually also having this issue elsewhere in the same module where I have a file with the base class "Base" and the extended class "Extended" where base.py needs to import extended.py so it can spawn instances of the expanded class and extended.py needs to import base.py so it can inherit the class.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Tip #1 is that they should not import each other because that indeed is circular.

Comment: So what can I do here to allow them each to see the classes in the other without circularly importing them? Or is it just not possible to have things in different files reference each other?

Comment: perhaps try specific imports:
`from foo import Foo`
etc